# Visual Basic Chart Bind Specific Rows of DataTable

Tags: datatable, rows

I am struggling to find an answer or if this is something that can be done.
I have a datatable "SFTable" and a chart "GPSChart" and I add series "SFLine" to it. 
I would like to specify beginning and end rows of the datatable that I want plotted. So if I only want to plot rows 45-234 out of the datatable, how would I go about that?
Not sure that databind is the best thing for this, but I don't really know any other options, I'm new to this. Thanks

```
If Not SFDrawn Then GPSChart.Series.Add("SFLine")
        With GPSChart.Series("SFLine")
            .ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line
            .Points.DataBind(TestDatabaseDataSet3.Tables("SFTable"), "Latitude", "Longitude", Nothing)
        End With
```

Comment: I have become held by this again in another part of my program. Any ideas?